# Pandas Profiling Import Error: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'

Tags: python, pandas, profiling

I have an issue with getting started with pandas profiling.

I tried loading pandas profiling, but upon installation this error pops up:

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
> anaconda-project 0.9.1 requires ruamel-yaml, which is not installed.
> sphinx 4.0.1 requires MarkupSafe<2.0, but you have markupsafe 2.1.1 which is incompatible.

I tried to fix it by installing an earlier version.
But if I install a MarkupSafe version below 2.0 as indicated, I get the following error:

> pandas-profiling 3.2.0 requires markupsafe~=2.1.1, but you have markupsafe 2.0.1 which is incompatible

Now, if I just try to use pandas profiling anyways, I get the error:

> cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'

This is the code I used:

```
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("WBNAME", sheetname = None)
prof = ProfileReport(df)
prof.to_file(output_file='output.html')
```

What exactly should I do here to be able to use pandas profiling?

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate case where things break down when your package code is being used by other software as a dependency, and you cannot foresee/test all use cases.

This worked for me:

```python
!pip uninstall markupsafe
!pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
```

Then, if using a notebook, restart and import `pandas-profiling`.

Rationale: reinstalling a previous version of `markupsafe` that still supports `soft_unicode` will throw this error:

```md
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. 
pandas-profiling 3.2.0 requires markupsafe~=2.1.1, but you have markupsafe 2.0.1 which is incompatible.
```

But, the line after still says:

```md
Successfully installed markupsafe-2.0.1
```

So, good2go.

Comment: Doesnt work !!!

Comment: What is your version stack, and what is the exact error that you are receiving? If you can provide more information, then maybe the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Try below lines, maybe it works

```
import pandas_profiling as pp
df = pd.read_excel("WBNAME", sheetname = None)
profile= pp.ProfileReport(df)
profile.to_file('pandas_profile_test.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you install your extension, just use the below commands:

```
pip install h5py
pip install typing-extensions
pip install wheel
```

and then install your extension. This worked for me.

Referred from this page: https://github.com/apple/turicreate/issues/3383

Comment: Doesn't work for me